# Material UI - access cross icon of search component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

is there a way I can access styles of cross icon inside Material UI InputBase type search component? I'm looking to change colour, size and thickness of it.
[image]

I'm using React v16, Material-core v4.9.1 and Material-icons v4.9.1

Comment: this X button isn't material ui, it's chrome styling the input with `type=search`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no class available for cross icon in Material UI, this is applied by browser.

This is what we get in Safari
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UtGc.png